# android chat application , how to implement last seen and typing and online feature like whatsapp

Tags: android, chat

How to implement features like last seen, online, typing like WhatsApp. Can parse be used for the same, if yes, how?

Comment: You will need to use sockets. Check out socket.io for Android.

Comment: could clarify your question more ,are you using any services , or you want to build this functionality??

Comment: I am using gcm to send and receive messages. Need to implement other three features. 1) show last seen timestamp of user. 2) show typing when user is typing 3)show online when user is using the app

Comment: Will surely check socket.io ,thanks

Comment: Are You Using Xmpp For Chat Or Socket Programming,if You Are Using Xmpp It has InBuilt Last Activity Support

Comment: Not using any server. Backend is php and mongodb on openshift.and mesage is sent using gcm .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my problem was as commented by, Bidhan A to use socket.io and it was really a great solution. Works fine. Thanks

Comment: can u plz share your demo so that beginner can learn soket.io and also implement chat features too.